# Unable to display data for jQuery Datatable with server side processing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I face the issue with jQuery Datatable server-side processing in ASP.NET Core 3.1. Server-side returns data as JSON but it is not displaying in Datatable.

Below is my controller side code

```
public IActionResult LoadData()
{
    var dict = Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());
    var draw = dict["draw"];
    var start = dict["start"];
    var length = dict["length"];
    
    ////Find Order Column
    var sortColumn = "Company";
    var sortColumnDir = "asc"; 
    int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
    int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
    
    DataSet ddata = GenralClass.GetCRMTestData((Convert.ToInt32(draw)-1)*100, 100);//GetCRMData();
    ddata.Tables[0].TableName = "data";
    var data = ddata;
     
    int recordsTotal = 34790;
     
    var jsonData = new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data };
    return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData));
}
```

Below is my view side code

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
    
            <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Company</th>
            <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Assignedto</th>
            <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Provider</th>
    
    
    
        </tr>
    </thead>
                          
                           
</table>
```

Below is my Jquery Code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
        pageLength: 100,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,   
        ajax: {
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadData", "SKU")',
            type: 'POST',              
            dataType: "json",                        
            columns: [
                { "data": "Company" },
                { "data": "Assignedto" },
                { "data": "Provider" },
            ]                       
        }
    });
});
```

I made some changes in startup.cs file in service configuration as below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
            });
        
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb")));
}
```

No error display when page load just empty table. I verify from the chrome network that data is returning from the server-side as the data attached below. I don't know what is wrong why the data is not showing. The paging number showing correct but the data is not showing. Any help.

```
{
    "draw":"1",
    "recordsFiltered":34790,
    "recordsTotal":34790,
    "data":{
        "data":[
            {
                "Company":"SHAN FOODS (PVT) LTD",
                "Assignedto":"Stock-Transfer",
                "Provider":"Stock-Transfer"
            },
            {
                "Company":"SHAN FOODS (PVT) LTD",
                "Assignedto":"Vermicelli (150gm)",
                "Provider":"030180010017"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @user18912521, your jQuery code `data = JSON.stringify(data),` was wrong, you should use `:` instead `=`.

Comment: Now I simplify ajax call but still not success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code as follows.

LoadData：

```
public IActionResult LoadData()
{
    //...
    var jsonData = new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data };
    return new JsonResult(new {json = jsonData });
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/SKU/LoadData",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
    });
});
    function OnSuccess(response) {         
        $('.dataTables-example').DataTable(
            {
                data: response.json.data,
                columns: [
                    { "data": "company" },
                    { "data": "assignedto" },
                    { "data": "provider" },
                ],
            });
    };
```

Test result:
[image]